# TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c'

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network, mnist

I created this simplified version of VGG16:

```
class VGG16COMBO(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, num_classes):
        super(VGG16COMBO, self).__init__()

        # calculate same padding:
        # (w - k + 2*p)/s + 1 = o
        # => p = (s(o-1) - w + k)/2

        self.block_1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1,
                      out_channels=64,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      # (1(32-1)- 32 + 3)/2 = 1
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64,
                      out_channels=64,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2),
                         stride=(2, 2))
        )

        self.block_2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64,
                      out_channels=128,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128,
                      out_channels=128,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2),
                         stride=(2, 2))
        )
        
        self.block_3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128,
                      out_channels=256,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256,
                      out_channels=256,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256,
                      out_channels=256,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2),
                         stride=(2, 2))
        )

        self.block_4 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256,
                      out_channels=512,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512,
                      out_channels=512,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512,
                      out_channels=512,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2),
                         stride=(2, 2))
        ) 


        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(2048, 4096),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.25),
            nn.Linear(4096, 4096),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.25),
            nn.Linear(4096, num_classes),
        )

    def forward(self, m, c):

        m = self.block_1(m)
        m = self.block_2(m)
        m = self.block_3(m)
        m = self.block_4(m)
        m = m.view(m.size(0), -1)
        m = self.classifier(m)

        c = self.block_1(c)
        c = self.block_2(c)
        c = self.block_3(c)
        c = self.block_4(c)
        c = c.view(c.size(0), -1)
        c = self.classifier(c)

        x = torch.cat((m, c), dim=1)
        return x
```

You can see that in forward I pass 2 elements, m and c. m is referred to MNIST, and c to CIFAR10, because i want a multi input neural network (or a network with shared weights).
Then:

```
modelcombo = VGG16COMBO(1).cuda()
print(modelcombo)

# Define an optimizier
import torch.optim as optim
optimizer = optim.SGD(modelcombo.parameters(), lr = 0.01)
# Define a loss 
criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
```

This is my training function:

```
#train da modificare con entrambi i dataset
def train(net, loaders, optimizer, criterion, epochs=20, dev=dev, save_param = False, model_name="valerio"):
    try:
        net = net.to(dev)
        #print(net)
        # Initialize history
        history_loss = {"train": [], "val": [], "test": []}
        history_accuracy = {"train": [], "val": [], "test": []}
        # Store the best val accuracy
        best_val_accuracy = 0

        # Process each epoch
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            # Initialize epoch variables
            sum_loss = {"train": 0, "val": 0, "test": 0}
            sum_accuracy = {"train": 0, "val": 0, "test": 0}
            # Process each split
            for split in ["train", "val", "test"]:
                if split == "train":
                  net.train()
                else:
                  net.eval()
                # Process each batch
                for (input, labels) in loaders[split]:
                    # Move to CUDA
                    input = input.to(dev)
                    labels = labels.to(dev)
                    # Reset gradients
                    optimizer.zero_grad()
                    # Compute output
                    pred = net(input)
                    #pred = pred.squeeze(dim=1) # Output shape is [Batch size, 1], but we want [Batch size]
                    labels = labels.unsqueeze(1)
                    labels = labels.float()
                    loss = criterion(pred, labels)
                    # Update loss
                    sum_loss[split] += loss.item()
                    # Check parameter update
                    if split == "train":
                        # Compute gradients
                        loss.backward()
                        # Optimize
                        optimizer.step()
                    # Compute accuracy
                    #pred_labels = pred.argmax(1) + 1
                    pred_labels = (pred >= 0.5).long() # Binarize predictions to 0 and 1
                    batch_accuracy = (pred_labels == labels).sum().item()/input.size(0)
                    # Update accuracy
                    sum_accuracy[split] += batch_accuracy
            # Compute epoch loss/accuracy
            epoch_loss = {split: sum_loss[split]/len(loaders[split]) for split in ["train", "val", "test"]}
            epoch_accuracy = {split: sum_accuracy[split]/len(loaders[split]) for split in ["train", "val", "test"]}

            # Store params at the best validation accuracy
            if save_param and epoch_accuracy["val"] > best_val_accuracy:
              #torch.save(net.state_dict(), f"{net.__class__.__name__}_best_val.pth")
              torch.save(net.state_dict(), f"{model_name}_best_val.pth")
              best_val_accuracy = epoch_accuracy["val"]

            # Update history
            for split in ["train", "val", "test"]:
                history_loss[split].append(epoch_loss[split])
                history_accuracy[split].append(epoch_accuracy[split])
            # Print info
            print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}:",
                  f"TrL={epoch_loss['train']:.4f},",
                  f"TrA={epoch_accuracy['train']:.4f},",
                  f"VL={epoch_loss['val']:.4f},",
                  f"VA={epoch_accuracy['val']:.4f},",
                  f"TeL={epoch_loss['test']:.4f},",
                  f"TeA={epoch_accuracy['test']:.4f},")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Interrupted")
    finally:
        # Plot loss
        plt.title("Loss")
        for split in ["train", "val", "test"]:
            plt.plot(history_loss[split], label=split)
        plt.legend()
        plt.show()
        # Plot accuracy
        plt.title("Accuracy")
        for split in ["train", "val", "test"]:
            plt.plot(history_accuracy[split], label=split)
        plt.legend()
        plt.show()
```

But when I do the training

```
# Train model
train(modelcombo, loaders, optimizer, criterion, epochs=10, dev=dev)
```

I obtain this error:

```
TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c'
```

What I have to change, the net or the training function? I think the problem is in the training function, because I have to pass loaders, and loaders_cifar, but I don't know how. In particular, I have to cat loaders of mnist and loaders of cifar before passing them to the training function, or I have to modify the `for (input, labels) in loaders[split]:` in something like `for (input, labels) in loaders[split] and loaders_cifar[split]:`?

EDIT: I created this function:

```
def itr_merge(*itrs):
    for itr in itrs:
        for v in itr:
            yield v
```

Edited the training function in this way:

```
#train da modificare con entrambi i dataset
def train2(net, loaders, loaders_cifar, optimizer, criterion, epochs=20, dev=dev, save_param = False, model_name="valerio"):
    try:
        net = net.to(dev)
        #print(net)
        # Initialize history
        history_loss = {"train": [], "val": [], "test": []}
        history_accuracy = {"train": [], "val": [], "test": []}
        # Store the best val accuracy
        best_val_accuracy = 0

        # Process each epoch
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            # Initialize epoch variables
            sum_loss = {"train": 0, "val": 0, "test": 0}
            sum_accuracy = {"train": 0, "val": 0, "test": 0}
            # Process each split
            for split in ["train", "val", "test"]:
                if split == "train":
                  net.train()
                else:
                  net.eval()
                # Process each batch
                for x in itr_merge(loaders[split], loaders_cifar[split]):
                  for (input, labels) in loaders[split]:
                      # Move to CUDA
                      input = input.to(dev)
                      labels = labels.to(dev)
                      # Reset gradients
                      optimizer.zero_grad()
                      # Compute output
                      pred = net(input)
                      #pred = pred.squeeze(dim=1) # Output shape is [Batch size, 1], but we want [Batch size]
                      labels = labels.unsqueeze(1)
                      labels = labels.float()
                      loss = criterion(pred, labels)
                      # Update loss
                      sum_loss[split] += loss.item()
                      # Check parameter update
                      if split == "train":
                          # Compute gradients
                          loss.backward()
                          # Optimize
                          optimizer.step()
                      # Compute accuracy
                      #pred_labels = pred.argmax(1) + 1
                      pred_labels = (pred >= 0.5).long() # Binarize predictions to 0 and 1
                      batch_accuracy = (pred_labels == labels).sum().item()/input.size(0)
                      # Update accuracy
                      sum_accuracy[split] += batch_accuracy
            # Compute epoch loss/accuracy
            epoch_loss = {split: sum_loss[split]/len(loaders[split]) for split in ["train", "val", "test"]}
            epoch_accuracy = {split: sum_accuracy[split]/len(loaders[split]) for split in ["train", "val", "test"]}

            # Store params at the best validation accuracy
            if save_param and epoch_accuracy["val"] > best_val_accuracy:
              #torch.save(net.state_dict(), f"{net.__class__.__name__}_best_val.pth")
              torch.save(net.state_dict(), f"{model_name}_best_val.pth")
              best_val_accuracy = epoch_accuracy["val"]

            # Update history
            for split in ["train", "val", "test"]:
                history_loss[split].append(epoch_loss[split])
                history_accuracy[split].append(epoch_accuracy[split])
            # Print info
            print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}:",
                  f"TrL={epoch_loss['train']:.4f},",
                  f"TrA={epoch_accuracy['train']:.4f},",
                  f"VL={epoch_loss['val']:.4f},",
                  f"VA={epoch_accuracy['val']:.4f},",
                  f"TeL={epoch_loss['test']:.4f},",
                  f"TeA={epoch_accuracy['test']:.4f},")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Interrupted")
    finally:
        # Plot loss
        plt.title("Loss")
        for split in ["train", "val", "test"]:
            plt.plot(history_loss[split], label=split)
        plt.legend()
        plt.show()
        # Plot accuracy
        plt.title("Accuracy")
        for split in ["train", "val", "test"]:
            plt.plot(history_accuracy[split], label=split)
        plt.legend()
        plt.show()
```

But I have still the same error

Comment: Where are you passing __m__ and __c__ these 2 in training ?

Comment: I am not passing, that's the problem. I pass only 1 "loaders", but i have to pass 2 loaders, one for mnist and one for cifar

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you have 2 inputs of data points , then pass 2 arguments here

```
pred = net(input1,input2) #input1 ---> mnist ,input2 ---> cifar
```

Comment: Yes, but I have to modify also the for loop, right?

Comment: make sure you r unziping both dataloaders in `for (input, labels) in loaders[split]`

Comment: Yes, but how can I do this? I am confused

Comment: I have to cat/flatten/merge the two loaders before the training or into the training I have to pick both the loaders?

Comment: correct you should have single dataloader for both the dataset, and then in training loop u have to unpack them

Comment: Do you know a way to create a dataloader for 2 datasets?

Comment: here try to merge both dataset https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html

Comment: and also check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65920729/custom-dataset-and-dataloader/65922745#65922745